# Running .net Saxon Transform in PowerShell with documentNode parameter

Tags: powershell, xslt-2.0, saxon

Trying to run xslt transform that previously have been tested in oxygen XML generates empty error.

The powershell code is

```
# ----------------------- Variables -----------------------
$inputXmlPath ='C:\temp\test.xml'
$finalOutputFilePath = 'C:\temp\result2.xml'
$xsltPath = 'C:\temp\validator.xsl'
#____________________________do____________________________
[xml]$dbOutput = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($dbOutputFilePath)
Transform -s:$inputXmlPath -xsl:$xsltPath -o:$finalOutputFilePath +databaseDoc='C:\temp\dbDoc.xml'
```

with the resulting error

```
Transform : 
At line:1 char:1
+ Transform -s:$inputXmlPath -xsl:$xsltPath -o:$finalOutputFilePath +da ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

The stylesheet requires a documentNode as the databaseDoc parameter.

Comment: If you add the `-t` option with e.g. `Transform -t ...`, do you then get any error message showing what failed? It at least should show you which Saxon version you run and whether the files were loaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen, realized now that the transform actually worked :) thanks to the -t flag....

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that finally gave the wanted result (aka no error message):

```
remove-item $finalOutputFilePath
start-process "Transform.exe" -ArgumentList "-s:$inputXmlPath -xsl:$xsltPath -  o:$finalOutputFilePath +databaseDoc=C:\temp\dbDoc.xml" -NoNewWindow -Wait
get-item $finalOutputFilePath
```